# How to Get EntireWeb Partner Id

Tags: json, web-services, api, search-engine

Im doing a Project to fetch the result from different search engines and extracting common results

I searched and Choose Google, Bing and EntireWeb.

I succeeded with the Google and Bing by getting the API keys from them, But I unable to Get the EntireWeb API key, they say The Partner Id is the Required parameter, I read their documentation

http://entireweb.com/search_api/implementation/

But there is no explanation about how to getting partner ID and too I mailed them before two days, but No reply From them

I found somebody in stackOverflow was using it, and asked a question about that

[android connecting to json/xml api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230381/android-connecting-to-json-xml-api)

So I know, anybody can access their API, but Its not possible without getting partner ID

Finally the Question is How to **Get the Key from EntireWeb**

Comment: I thought they will provide Partner ID **If I submit a site**, and I tried that too, But not succeeded, any help??

Comment: I'm looking for this too

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.entireweb.com/services/ the Search API is not available anymore. Also, the [Search API Documentation](http://entireweb.com/support/searchapi/Entireweb_Search_API.pdf) is not found.