# Custom ListView adapter using URL image getting error 'StrictMode'

Tags: android, listview, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-strictmode

İ am using this custom adapter for showing youtube thumbnail.

```
public class MyMedyaAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
    Context context;
    int layout;
    List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data;
    String[] from;
    int[] to;

    String resimURL = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/{0}/0.jpg";

    public MyMedyaAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        this.context = context;
        this.layout = resource;
        this.data = data;
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);

        TextView metin = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_medya_text);

        String baslik = data.get(position).get(from[0]) + "";
        baslik = baslik.replace(".pdf", "");

        metin.setText(baslik);

        if (from.length > 1) {
            final ImageView resim = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_medya_image);

            final int p2 = position;

            String resimID = data.get(p2).get(from[1])+"";

            String rowImage = resimURL.replace("{0}", resimID);
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(rowImage).getContent());
                resim.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

adding adapter to listview with this code;

```
public class VideoThered extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, MyMedyaAdapter> {

        @Override
        protected MyMedyaAdapter doInBackground(Void... params) {

            List<HashMap<String, String>> response = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            try {
                                //JSON request
                response = new JsonHelper().GetVideoEntitys();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                response = null;
            }

            if (response != null) {
                adapter = new MyMedyaAdapter(ctx, response, R.layout.row_medya, from, to);
            }
            else
            {
                adapter = null;
            }
            return adapter;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(MyMedyaAdapter result) {
            if (result != null) {
                                //StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork() error with this line on honeycomb
                listVideolar.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }


    }
```

i am getting /StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork() error.

How can i manage to show row images from web and not getting this error?

i am using listview main data from AsyncTask.
 in this data list, each item has a unique youtube video id. with this id i am getting video thumbnails from web. but on my custom adapter did not use AsyncTask. i know that's the problem. 
But how can i manage to my custom adaptor to use AsyncTask?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7730547/1187845

answer in this link was very helpfull.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the error because you do network access in the UI thread. This is considered bad, because network access takes a long time and thus blocks the UI.

To solve this, you can write an `AsyncTask` that pulls the data from the net within its `doInBackground` method and then in `onPostExecute` fills the view with the bitmap/drawable.
I think the Android documentation has an example for this scenario, but I can't find it right now.

You can also have a look at this [source code snippet](https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/blob/master/src/de/bsd/zwitscher/OneTweetActivity.java#L934), `DownloadUserImageTask` from my Zwitscher app; the url is retrieved from the passed User object. The picture is then added to the view in

```
userPictureView.setImageBitmap(result);
```