# Application not working in android 4.0 and above

Tags: android, gridview, android-edittext

I am trying to show image and text in edit text, but its not working in ice-cream sandwich and Jellybean..
 It's working fine in below versions.

When activity is paused and resumed again, it displays image names instead of image in edit text along with text..

Please refer the image and related code

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
        OnItemClickListener {

     String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
            + "/Emoticons";


HashMap<String, Integer> emoticons = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();

ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

Bitmap bitmap;

EditText editText;

ImageButton cat_one;

ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();

View view;

CharSequence[] namesList = { "Email"};

Dialog dialog;

GridView gridView;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);



    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {

        File sd = new File(path);

        if (!sd.exists())
            sd.mkdirs();

    }


    addComponents();

    addListeners();
}

private void fillArrayList() {

    Iterator<Entry<String, Integer>> iterator = emoticons.entrySet()
            .iterator();

    Log.d("Iterator", iterator.toString());

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {

        Entry<String, Integer> entry = iterator.next();

        Log.d("Entry", entry.getKey());

        arrayList.add(entry.getKey());

    }
}

private void getCategory(String cat_name) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (name.size() > 0)
        name.clear();

    if (emoticons.size() > 0)
        emoticons.clear();

    if (arrayList.size() > 0)
        arrayList.clear();

    Field names[] = R.drawable.class.getFields();

    for (Field f : names) {

        if (f.getName().contains(cat_name)) {

            name.add(f.getName());

        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++) {

        int id = getResources().getIdentifier(name.get(i), "drawable",
                getPackageName());

        Log.d("Drawable Folder", name.get(i).toString());
        emoticons.put(name.get(i), id);

    }
    fillArrayList();
}

private void addListeners() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    cat_one.setOnClickListener(this);

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

private void addComponents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    editText.requestFocus();

    view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup, null);

    gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);

    dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.DialogSlideAnim);

    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);

    Window window = dialog.getWindow();

    window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);

    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);

    dialog.setContentView(view);

    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);


    cat_one = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.category_one);



}

public Spannable getSmiledText(Context context, String text) {

    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);

    int index;

    for (index = 0; index < builder.length(); index++) {

        for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : emoticons.entrySet()) {

            int length = entry.getKey().length();

            if (index + length > builder.length())

                continue;

            if (builder.subSequence(index, index + length).toString()
                    .equals(entry.getKey())) {

                builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(context, entry.getValue()),
                        index, index + length,
                        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

                index += length - 1;

                break;

            }
        }
    }
    return builder;
}

class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public int getCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return arrayList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(
                R.layout.row, null);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                emoticons.get(arrayList.get(position))));

        Log.d(getLocalClassName(),
                String.valueOf(emoticons.get(arrayList.get(position))));

        return convertView;
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    if (v == cat_one) {


        getCategory("good");

        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter());

    }

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String value = gridView.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString();

    Spannable spannable = getSmiledText(MainActivity.this, value);

    SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(
            editText.getText()).append(spannable).append(" ");

    editText.setText(ssb);
    editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
    editText.setCursorVisible(true);
}
  }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your question is devoid of any helpful specifics.

Comment: What have you done? Have you checked the logs? the DDMS output?? See what happens at DDMS when you resume again. and paste the logs here.

Comment: I can post related code, but there are lots of other things that i can't post. is that ok?

Comment: What image? Can you provide code of where you create and display it? Are you perhaps using an API that's not available in previous versions?

Comment: As you can see text and images, but when i run on ice-cream sandwich and jellybean it shows text and image name as text instead of actual image

Comment: What? The images in the post? How does that help? You're trying to run this on Android, not HTML, right?

Comment: @MiteshAgrawal : please put AndroidManifest.xml here

Comment: @MiteshAgrawal First image is below 4.0 and second is above, right?

Comment: @RobinHood No Both the images are of above 4.0..

Comment: So your ImageSpans stop working on pause/resume?

Comment: How are you saving/reinstantiating the states of all of these arrays in onPause and onResume?  Almost like when the app resumes it is referencing stale data somewhere.

Comment: Or perhaps null views on onPause, recreate them onResume?

Comment: @MiteshAgrawal Are you using `android:bufferType="spannable"` for your `EditText`s?

Comment: hi @droiddev, have you solved the issue? I am facing exactly the same issue..can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

I think we would need a bit of tracing to have a better idea of what is going wrong. But as you cant load the images, I was wondering if it could be that you lost access to the external storage directory

Comment: I am loading images from resources(drawable)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the use of **[Asynctask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)** when you load the images, that will solve your problem, I had the same issue.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

http://android-developers.blogspot.mx/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html

[Using AsyncTask to load Images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729133/using-asynctask-to-load-images-in-listview)