# android use AsyncTask load image from sdcard

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

if you're already know the images path like "/mnt/sdcard/newphoto"!how to using AsyncTask load
 images from that path and fill with listview,

Comment: You cannot update your UI in your background thread

Comment: have a look at this. Same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729133/using-asynctask-to-load-images-in-listview

Comment: you can retrieve the file from asyncTask however update the imageView in the `onPostExecute()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this function in the `AsyncTask<String><Void><Bitmap>` within `doInBackground`:

```
 ArrayList<String> f = new ArrayList<String>();   // list of available files in  path
File[] listFile;

public void getSdcardImages()
{
File file= new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"MyFolder");

if (file.isDirectory())
{
    listFile = file.listFiles();


    for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++)
    {

        f.add(listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());

    }
}
}
```

then in `onPostExecute(Bitmap b)` you can update the images

Comment: didn't need to decodefile to bitmap?