# ViewHolder GridView laggy

Tags: java, android, image, gridview, bitmap

I´m using the first time `ViewHolder` with `GridView` and i´m new to android/java
It´s working a lot of better then with `ImageView`.

But the biggest problem i have is that scrolling is laggy.
I have two questions:

First one: What can I do to make performance better?
Second one: Can I use and how can I use `BitmapWorkerTask`/`AsyncTask` with it?

What I tried was `android:scrollingCache="false"` as everybody is writting but it seems that performance is a little bit better for me with `android:scrollingCache="true"`.

Code:

**Layout**

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
                  android:orientation="vertical"  
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
                  android:padding="10dp">  
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/ic_launcher"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:persistentDrawingCache="scrolling"
    android:scrollingCache="true"
    android:animationCache="false"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true"
    /> 

    </LinearLayout>
```

**ImageAdapter**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;



public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater; 


    // Keep all Images in array about 600
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {

};
// Constructor
    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {   
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);  
           mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }



 // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the     
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {     
     ViewHolder holder;
       if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled,     
             convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.categorycontent, null);  
           convertView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(130, 130));  
          holder = new ViewHolder();  
             holder.icon = (ImageView )convertView.findViewById(R.id.ic_launcher);  
             convertView.setTag(holder);  
         } else {  
             holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

         }  
holder.icon.setAdjustViewBounds(true);  
holder.icon.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);     
holder.icon.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);  
return convertView;     
    }     
    class ViewHolder {  
        ImageView icon;  
    }  }
```

I hope you dudes have some ideas for me :)

**NewCodewithErrors**

```
    }

    class ViewHolder {  
        ImageView icon;  
    } 

 // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the     
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {     
     ViewHolder holder;
       if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled,     
             convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.categorycontent, null);  
           convertView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(130, 130));  
          holder = new ViewHolder();  
             holder.icon = (ImageView )convertView.findViewById(R.id.ic_launcher);  
             convertView.setTag(holder);  
         } else {  
             holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

         }  
holder.icon.setAdjustViewBounds(true);  
holder.icon.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);     
holder.icon.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

//Here i have the errors:
//The constructor ImageAdapter.LoadImage() is undefine ImageAdapter.java
//The method execute(Integer...) in the type AsyncTask<Integer,Void,Bitmap> is not 
//applicable for the arguments (View) ImageAdapter.java

new LoadImage().execute(convertView);

return convertView;     
    }   


    private class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {

        private ImageView imv;

        public LoadImage(ImageView imv) {
            this.imv = imv;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

            if (result != null && imv != null) {
                imv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imv.setImageBitmap(result);
            } else {
                imv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(),
                    params[0]);
            return bitmap;
        }

    }}
```

Comment: You are loading images in the UI thats why your grid scroll is lagging..try to load it in Asynchtask..

Comment: The code seems fine to me. I have used this multiple times, but I have never seen any scroll lag. Can you please explain the issue in a bit more detail.

Comment: Could you guide me how to do that? or do you know a good tutorial or something else? thx @kalyanpvs

Comment: @skulldeath420 with small modification to the given kink,,you will get http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729133/using-asynctask-to-load-images-in-listview

Comment: @KKD
I´m making and learning on an app with 4 tabs(fragment) and fullscreenactivity were i can share images.
On the first tab what is the code i posted i try that new and better solution and because that gridview tab has a little bit more then 600 pictures in it.

The image loading is perfect but if i scroll fast because let´s say i want a picture from the end of the gridview it freeze and lags for a few seconds and that i don´t want.
If i scroll really slow performance is not great but okay...

Comment: I don´t get it what modifications are needed :(

If i put the line new LoadImage()... above the line return convertView and add at the end of my code that class LoadImage
I have the error 
The constructor ImageAdapter.LoadImage() is undefined ImageAdapter.java


@kalyanpvs

Comment: @skulldeath420 ok..wait i will post..

Comment: @skulldeath420 change like that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First take inner class in your Adapter like..

```
private class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {

    private ImageView imv;

    public LoadImage(ImageView imv) {
        this.imv = imv;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

        if (result != null && imv != null) {
            imv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imv.setImageBitmap(result);
        } else {
            imv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(),
                params[0]);
        return bitmap;
    }

}
```

And call it above the line return convertView

```
new LoadImage(holder.icon).execute(mThumbIds[position]);
```

Comment: I still have the same error with a new one.
I added the new code in my question maybe you can see what i´m doing wrong.

Comment: //The constructor ImageAdapter.LoadImage() is undefine ImageAdapter.java
//The method execute(Integer...) in the type AsyncTask<Integer,Void,Bitmap> is not 
//applicable for the arguments (View) ImageAdapter.java

I added the code above.

Comment: @skulldeath420 have you called like this **new LoadImage(holder.icon).execute(mThumbIds[position]);**

Comment: yes it´s working i didn´t see that with holder.icon and so on :)
But it´s not smoother it´s still the same and now the pictures are on the wrong place i mean you can see that it´s loading the new ones but that´s no problem for me.
Do you have another idea for the performance?

Comment: @skulldeath420 Nope..thats the only solution..and move this two holder.icon.setAdjustViewBounds(true);  
holder.icon.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);  into inside of if(convertview==null) block

Comment: ok i solved the problem with the pictures on wrong place with:
android:scrollingCache="false"
but it´s still laggy

Comment: add this to your gridview in xml "android:fastScrollEnabled=true"

Comment: wrong information with cache false it takes longer to load..
and and moving the lines i think helped a little bit.
Do you know if it´s possible to set a scroll speed limit?
So let´s say i try to scroll over the display 4 times in a second but it only use one scroll with the finger?
Or should i try to use a DiskLruCache?

Comment: i have fast scroll enabled.

Comment: @skulldeath420 You cant set the speed of scroll..that too dont expect that much scroll on image..its not text messages you are showing..its large Bitmap objects..

Comment: i understand now what you mean.
So do you think if i use DiskLruCache it could be better?